# multiple if condition in vuejs - how to get it work

Tags: vue.js

I literally just started messing aroung with vuejs. I'm having problem with multiple if conditions.

This is how I'm trying to get it work:

```
 <td v-if="!editing && selectedID === user.id">{{user.name}}</td>
 <td v-else>
   <input type="text" v-model="user.name" />
 </td>
```

User clicks on edit button and sets editing prop to true, then if next condition is true it should display input, but it doesnt work. Don't know why.

Comment: Can you clarify "it doesn't work"? The template fragment looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if the rest of your code and markup is correct. Since we can't see the rest of your code, I will venture a guess that your "td" elements are not in a "table" element?   If that is the case it won't work. See this working example to observe the difference https://jsfiddle.net/skribe/sLaf7m0e/

```
<!-- Working Code -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td v-if="!editing && selectedId === user.id">{{user.name}}</td>
    <td v-else>
      <input type="text" v-model="user.name" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<!-- Non Working Code -->
<div>
  <tr>
    <td v-if="!editing && selectedId === user.id">{{user.name}}</td>
    <td v-else>
       <input type="text" v-model="user.name" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Why this is the case is if you inspect the dom you will find that because proper markup for tables is not used the `tr` and `td` elements are ignored causing all the fields to be rendered in a single `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

you are showing input on the else case..... you have to do it like this instead :

```
    <td v-if="editing && selectedID === user.id">
        {{user.name}}
        <input type="text" v-model="user.name"/>
    </td>
    <td v-else>
        <!-- do something else if condition is false -->
   </td>
```